# Avoid React overdrawing from previous props update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nvd3.js

Below I am describing the sequence of events triggered by clicking on the `NavItem` of my app:

I have a `ControlledTabs` `React` component that has a child `MarkerGenesChart` which has a child `ScatterChart`. Inside the topmost `ControlledTabs` component upon switching from one `NavItem` to another I am calling `setState()` which triggers `componentWillReceiveProps()` in the `MarkerGenesChart` because it modifies some of the props that I am passing to it. Then, `MarkerGenesChart` in its `componentWillReceiveProps` is calling `setState()` that triggers the `componentWillReceiveProps` of the child `ScatterChart`. The issue is that the action `switching the NavItem` causes my childmost element `ScatterChart` to call `componentWillReceiveProps()` twice: once for the topmost component, and another time for the middle one. The first time it triggers the `ScatterChart` to draw chart with the old data, and the second time it adds the updated one without removing the old.

Here is how I am updating the data in `ScatterChart` component:

```
    d3.select(node)
        .datum(data_func);
    chart.update();
```

I am using `nvd3` `scatterChart` and there it has `nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);`. When I am just resizing the window everything becomes like I want it to be. How could I clean up the data before adding new one? Or maybe I should somehwere `this.forceUpdate()` but I tried it nearly everywhere and can not make it to work.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

> Update

I can partially solve it by introducing a global counter and counting the number of times `componentWillReceiveProps()` in `ScatterChart` is called, but that is a wrong way to go obviously.

Answer (score 1):

```
chart.update();
this.forceUpdate();
```

calling forceUpdate() is not recommended, but this is by far the simplest approach.

Answer (score 0):

I was drawing the chart both in `componentDidUpdate()` and in `componentWillReceiveProps()` because some of my functionalities would be broken if I did not do that. `componentWillReceiveProps` was drawing the old data, and then `componentDidUpdate()` was adding the new one. That is why I was having the issue, and not because `componentWillReceiveProps` was called twice. I completely removed `componentWillReceiveProps` and  fixed the other part of my app that was broken by that removal.

Comment: you never draw anything in componentDidUpdate, it was drawn in render() function.

Comment: Yes, but I was calling the function `createScatterChart` that was drawing the chart using the `render`.

Comment: Actually I am not sure on that. I am modifying the `DOM` directly by using `createScatterChart`. It is still hijacked by `React` and drawn by the `render()` method even though I am directly accessing the `DOM` and appending/removing elements there?